# Cracking an MD5 password with little info to go off of

Tags: hash, password-cracking, md5, hashcat

I am taking a security class and part of an assignment this week is to crack a given MD5 hash.

All the professor has given us for this task is the hash, the knowledge that the password is 6 or 7 keystrokes, and that it *might* contain the null terminator at the end. He suggests using any hash cracking program, of which I have been trying hashcat.

Since I don't know anything about the charset of the password I have simply been running a brute force attack on the hash for several hours due to the low number of characters but now the passwords being tried are longer than the maximum possible length.

This was all the information given to us and he has been fairly unresponsive in terms of questions.

Comment: You should probably read the manual of hashcat for how to configure the charset it uses - and to include a null termination.

Comment: Did your professor say that the password is 7 characters long if and only if the password ends with the null terminator?  For example, "abcdef" and "abcdef\n" are possible, but "abcdefg" is not?  If so, this reduces the search space considerably.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Whenever asking for troubleshooting help (I'm assuming you want to know why hashcat isn't following your directives?) ***always*** include the command you used and the actual output, redacted, if necessary. Don't just provide a narrative summary of what you did and saw.

Comment: Besides learning hashcat you can also google unsalted hashes to see if there is a publicly cracked value available for it